# Task.Factory.FromAsync call runs synchronously

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am using Task.Factory.FromAsync to  publish a message (to rabbitmq) asynchronously. The following code seems to run synchronously. "End of main" line is displayed on the console after "In begin publish method".

SHouldn't the control be returned to the main thread and "End Of Main" be displayed when the code "awaits" at Task.Factory.FromAsync?

```
    private async void TestAsync()
    {
        int x = await TryAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("End of Main");
    }

    async static Task<int> TryAsync()
    {

        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(BeginPublish("This is message", new AsyncCallback(GetPublishResult), null), EndPublish);

        return 1;
    }


    public static IAsyncResult BeginPublish(string message, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {

        TaskCompletionSource<int> t = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

       //Simulate call to rabbitmq
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Console.WriteLine("In begin publish method");

        return t.Task;
    }

    private static void EndPublish(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Console.WriteLine("End Publish method completed");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following code seems to run synchronously. "End of main" line is displayed on the console after "In begin publish method".

That's correct.  The main method cannot continue execution until it has finished *starting* the `Task`.  Your `BeginPublish` method is meant to *start* the task, and return as quickly as possible, letting all of the work happen without blocking.  The caller isn't *able* to continue execution until it is given the `IAsyncResult` that the method returns.

Comment: Thanks. So how do I make the call so that the main thread is released and continues execution? I did not want to use Task.Run as the call to RabbitMQ is a network call and did not want to block the "worker" thread for this. RabbitMQ as of now, doe s not provide async-await feature for its BasicPublish method.

Comment: @user1399653 It would need to provide an asynchronous operation to you.  You could convert it to a task based model if they provided an asynchronous operation using a different asynchronous model than tasks, but if they only provide synchronous operations then there's nothing you can do to avoid creating a thread to sit there and wait for it.